# Show only specific days on calendar

Tags: bash, calendar, dialog

I want to know if it's possible to show only specific days in a calendar. I mean, for example, I know that I can create a dialog box with a calendar using:

dialog --title "Test" --calendar "Date:" 0 0

And it shows every day on the specific months and so on.

But I want to know if I can show only the days like 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30 in the same dialog box, but I don't know how to do it or if it can be done that way using that dialog option.

Comment: No, it doesn't do that (you would have to modify the program).

Comment: @ThomasDickey not even using the --date-format option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dialog` does not do what was asked.  Source code is provided; you could modify it.

The documentation says

> [**`--calendar`** *text height width day month year*](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Box-Options)
>   A calendar box displays *month*, *day* and *year*  in  separately  adjustable  windows.   If  the  values  for day, month or year are
>   missing or negative, the current date's corresponding values are
>   used.   You  can  increment  or decrement any of those using the
>   left-, up-, right-, and down-arrows.  Use vi-style **`h`**, **`j`**, **`k`** and **`l`**
>   for  moving  around  the  array  of days in a month.  Use tab or
>   backtab to move between windows.  If the year is given as  zero,
>   the current date is used as an initial value.

On  exit,  the  date is printed in the form *day/month/year*.  The
format can be overridden using the **`--date-format`** option.

and

> [**`--date-format`** *format*](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/manpage/dialog.html#h3-Common-Options)
>   If the host provides [`strftime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html), this option allows you to specify
>   the format of the date printed for the **`--calendar`**  widget.   The
>   time of day (hour, minute, second) are the current local time.

While the --calendar description refers to an *array* of days, and *separately adjustable windows*, it does not go into excessive detail to note that the windows for *month*, *day* and *year* are used to update the *array*, and that the widget shows all of the days for each month.

The **`--date-format`** option is used to change the way the result is reported to the shell, and has no effect on the way the month is shown on the screen.

Comment: It looks like I'll have to use it as it is then...thanks for taking some of your time to answer my question. I really appreciated it.